# @JsonIgnoreProperties for dynamic number of parameters

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to ignore number of properties (which I get from UI) like

filtervalue0, filtervalue1, filtervalue2, etc

I do however get this count from UI

i.e. if  filterscount = 3
I know, there would be 
filtervalue0, filtervalue1, filtervalue2

Is it possible to have this work dynamically (i.e. @JsonIgnoreProperties )

Comment: `@JsonIgnoreProperties` won't do you much good. The class is already compiled when you get your value from the UI. But have a look at [`@JsonFilter`](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@JsonFilter` to dynamically filter fields to `Serialization` or `Deserialization`.

For example:

```
@JsonFilter("myFilter")
static class Bean {
    public String filtervalue0 = "a";
    public String filtervalue1 = "b";
    public int filtercount = 1;
    public int totalFilters = 2;
}

static void test() throws JsonProcessingException{
    Bean value = new Bean();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Set<String> filtersToExclude = new HashSet<>();

    //logic for applying filter
    for(int i=value.totalFilters-1; i>value.totalFilters-value.filtercount-1; i--){
        filtersToExclude.add("filtervalue"+i);
    }

   //dynamic field filtering is provided by FilterProvider
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("myFilter",
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(filtersToExclude));
    String json = mapper.setFilterProvider(filters).writeValueAsString(value);
    System.out.println(json); // prints {"filtervalue1":"b"}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    test();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And how do I handle the getters/setters for them? Do I have to specify all of the getters/setters ?

Comment: And can I not use @JsonIgnoreProperties ...if I just want to silence the Unrecognized field error which I get currently ?

Comment: And do I have to write this code for @JsonFilter inside MyPojoClass (where I have the attributes mapping..that is those coming from UI request)

Comment: @testndtv You do need implement getters/setters. For suppressing Unrecognized field error use "mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)"

Comment: Also @JsonFilter needs to be applied at bean/pojo class which is undergoing serialization/deserialization